# SQL query - how to put conditions in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I'm new to SQL and I wonder if it is possible to put a condition after the `WHERE` clause. More specifically I'm trying to find out "which item have been sold to two people" within my database.

I've managed to connect all the items that have been sold to people and want a condition that gives only the items that have been sold to two people. I have tried using `COUNT(customer_id)` in `WHERE` clause but it gives "aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause".

**Edit:**

the **database** tables are:

```
books((book_id), title, author_id, subject_id) 
publishers((publisher_id), name, address) 
authors((author_id), last_name, first_name) 
stock((isbn), cost, retail_price, stock) 
shipments((shipment_id), customer_id, isbn, ship_date) 
customers((customer_id), last_name, first_name) 
editions((isbn), book_id, edition, publisher_id, publication_date) 
subjects((subject_id), subject, location)
```

and my current **query** is:

```
SELECT title, first_name, last_name 
FROM books, shipments, customers, editions 
WHERE books.book_id = editions.book_id 
AND editions.isbn = shipments.isbn 
AND shipments.customer_id = customers.customer_id 
AND COUNT(customers.customer_id) = 2;
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: the database is: 
books((book_id), title, author_id, subject_id) 
publishers((publisher_id), name, address) 
authors((author_id), last_name, first_name) 
stock((isbn), cost, retail_price, stock) 
shipments((shipment_id), customer_id, isbn, ship_date) 
customers((customer_id), last_name, first_name) 
editions((isbn), book_id, edition, publisher_id, publication_date) 
subjects((subject_id), subject, location)

Comment: and my current query is:
SELECT title, first_name, last_name FROM books, shipments, customers, editions WHERE books.book_id = editions.book_id AND editions.isbn = shipments.isbn AND shipments.customer_id = customers.customer_id AND COUNT(customers.customer_id) = 2;

Comment: aggregates functions can only be applied in SELECT & HAVING CLAUSE.

Comment: Don't put code or additional information in comments. **Edit** your question and put the `create table` statement into your question (don't forget to format it using the `{}` button)

Comment: it is better you use `group by` clause on `cusotmer.coustomer_id` and `having` clause with `Count(customer.customor_id) = 2`

Comment: Thanks everybody! The HAVING clause solved it. I'll try to write my text better next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING` clause, like this:

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING aggregate_function(column_name) operator val
```

ue;

Comment: Good! please vote up and mark as the correct answer.

Comment: I was going to upvote this answer until I read your request for votes.  Then I changed my mind.

Comment: My request was meant for the question opener only because he is new here, but as you want my friend it's ok.

Comment: @Ptru . . . If this answers your question and is your preferred answer, then you should *accept* the answer.

Comment: notwithstanding the fact you weren't begging for people's votes, the only thing that should dictate whether someone upvotes you is whether they think the answer is helpful to the question; the reader's opinion on (their misinterpretation of) the comments aren't relevant. so, upvoted.

Comment: Sure! I'm new to this stackoverflow thing. I just clicked the accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to use proper `join` syntax and table aliases:

```
SELECT b.title, c.first_name, c.last_name 
FROM books b join
     editions e
     on b.book_id = e.book_id  join
     shipments s
     on e.isbn = s.isbn join
     customers c
     on s.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY title, first_name, last_name 
HAVING COUNT(customers.customer_id) = 2;
```

The answer to your question is the `HAVING` clause along with a `GROUP BY`.